# How to evaluate the above integration? Please anyone help me out?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve
$$\int \frac{45}{31x+(x^2)^{1/2}} dx$$?
I am trying this question by taking out $x^2$ out of the root sign. So, after taking out $x^2$ out of the root sign I am getting $|x|$. So, the final integration is
$$\int \frac{45}{31x+|x|} dx$$.
Now the problem is that I can't write $|x|$ as $x\operatorname{sgn}(x)$, because $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=0$ when $x=0$. So, I am facing problem in this question. Please help me out with this question.

Comment: The main problem is that I am confused whether to write |$x$| as +$x$ or $-$$x$.

Comment: Why not just consider $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ separately?

Comment: Then there will exists 2 integrals according to your statement @Klaus.

Comment: Are 2 integrands possible for an indefinite integral?

Comment: @ShivamKumar It is possible but the only constraint is that the resulting function will not be an "antiderivative". It will be differentiable everywhere except at $0$. I guess at your level (I presume high school or basic IIT JEE level) it won't be highly inappropriate to think of $\frac{45}{32}\ln(x)$ if $x>0$ and $\frac{45}{30}\ln(-x)$ if $x<0$ , a sufficient enough description.  In any case, when you write $\int\frac{1}{x}=\ln(|x|)+C$ then it is immediately implied that the function on the right is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I am currently an Undergraduate student@Dovahkiin.

Comment: If $x$$>$0, then the result of the above integration will be (45$/$32)[(ln|$x$|)+C and if $x$$<$0, then the result of the above integration will be (3$/$2)[(ln|$x$|)+C]@Dovahkiin

Comment: Clearly,  two different results are occurring. Is that possible?

Comment: @ShivamKumar It's not two different results. By your logic, the $|x|$ is actually two functions rather than one. It's just that the definition changes in the context of it's domain. Like I said, you are probably used to writing $\int \frac{1}{x}=\ln(x)+C$. This is wrong. One has to write $\ln(|x|)+C$ and this function is not continuous at $0$. So this is not an antiderivative and neither an "indefinite integral". It's just a shorthand to mean that $\ln(|x|)$ is not differentiable, but if $x>0$, then the derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$ and if $x<0$ also $\frac{1}{x}$ in a small interval around $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on keeping this as an indefinite integral then we can follow on from your work. From the correct statement $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\neq x$ we obtain the following pieces

$$I = \begin{cases} \frac{45}{32}\log( x) + C_1 & x>0 \\ \frac{3}{2}\log(-x) +C_2 & x<0 \end{cases}$$

This is not unusual, as even in the usual case we have a piecewise function

$$\int \frac{dx}{x} = \begin{cases}\log(x)+C_1 & x>0 \\ \log(-x)+C_2 & x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: You are correct@Ninad Munshi. But can an indefinite integral have 2 different solutions?

Comment: @ShivamKumar what are you talking about? This is one solution

Comment: No, clearly 2 solutions are occuring@Ninad Munshi

Comment: Actually in my school life, during examination time in case of an indefinite integral, I used to write only one solution. Our teachers also used to tell us to write only one solution.

Comment: Generally we don't write $$\int (1/x)dx$$= $ln$($x$)$+$$C_1$ for $x$$>$0 and $ln$($-x$)$+$$C_2$ for $x$$<$0.

Comment: But thank you@Ninad Munshi for atleast trying out this question.

Comment: Generally $$\int (1/x)dx$$=$ln$$|$$x$$|$$+$$C$

Comment: @ShivamKumar most of what you're saying is incorrect and you seem to refuse help or to see reason with the barrage of comments you are providing me

Comment: if you check in most of the books(written by any mathematician) then you will get to know that $$\int (1/x)dx$$=$ln$$|$$x$$|$+$C$. @Ninad Munshi.

Comment: I am not saying your process is incorrect. Your process is correct. But generally we don't write the integration of (1/$x$) $dx$ to be $ln$($x$)+$C_1$ for $x$$>$0 and $ln$($-x$)+$C_2$ for $x$$<$0.@ Ninad Munshi

Comment: You have a deep confusion as to what piecewise functions actually mean. When the integrand is piecewise, why would you expect a non-piecewise antiderivative? And why on Earth do you have the idea that a piecewise function is two functions? I could have just as easily written my answer as $$\frac{45x}{31x+|x|}\log|x|$$ but that doesn't make it any more or less correct (it simply makes the answer less general so arguably more wrong). Everything you're saying about "two functions" is an illusion. A piecewise function is one function.

Comment: "And because it's not usually written" is a terrible argument. I have to be this precise because "the way it's usually written" is the reason you have this misconception in the first place. Mathematicians who wrote those books can use that shorthand because they understand what these shorthands mean and don't want to have to write piecewise brackets all day. You, on the other hand, should not be using shorthands if you aren't understanding their point.

Comment: Ok. Fine. Kindly please give me the definition of piecewise function. I really don't know the definition of piecewise function@Ninad Munshi.

Comment: @ShivamKumar Do you honestly expect to learn the basics of 12th grade calculus in the comment section of a single post? It's okay if you have doubts and misunderstandings. In that case, you should pick up a book say that of Thomas,Finney and then study up piecewise functions or other relevant details and then ask your queries in this forum. As Ninad points out, the root of your issue is that you are treating $f(x)=\begin{cases}\ln(x)+C_{1}\,,x>0\\ \ln(-x)+C_{2}\,,x<0\end{cases}$ as two separate functions. Or you are confused when we drop the curly braces and thinking of it as two functions.